# Enable decoration on rm output

Tags: linux, bash, colors

*This is not a question about PS1.*

I am using bash, my prompt is colorful, output from ls has color, but rm outputs this:

```
20:08:15 ~> rm test.txt
rm: cannot remove âtest.txtâ: No such file or directory
20:08:30 ~>
```

How do I get `âtest.txtâ` to print properly?

env:

```
20:19:45 ~> cat env.txt
XDG_SESSION_ID=1336
TERM=xterm
SHELL=/bin/bash
SSH_TTY=/dev/pts/0
USER=ubuntu
LS_COLORS= ...really long line...
MAIL=/var/mail/ubuntu
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin ...
PWD=/home/ubuntu
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
PS1=\[\e[0;32m\]\t \W>\[\e[1;37m\]
SHLVL=1
HOME=/home/ubuntu
LOGNAME=ubuntu
LESSOPEN=| /usr/bin/lesspipe %s
XDG_RUNTIME_DIR=/run/user/1000
LESSCLOSE=/usr/bin/lesspipe %s %s
_=/usr/bin/env
```

Comment: It would help if you included the output of the `env` command in your question. Be sure to edit out any sensitive data.

Comment: Not really a bash question; rather, it's a question explicitly about the version of `rm` you have installed (which will typically come from the GNU coreutils package for a Linux system).

Comment: Does 'rm' use the 'ls' options? I notice the same mangling in the output from 'man'.

Comment: I'd expect it not to. I mean, nothing in its documentation says it will.

Comment: Waitaminute, let's back up here. Is your question about color, or is it about the quotes around filenames not using the characters you expect? Because that latter issue isn't about color at all.

Comment: It is about the strange characters around the filenames, which I am not sure are quotes or some formatting escape codes. I should mention this is a Putty terminal window.

Comment: What do you get if you export `LC_ALL=C`?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not about programming. Try https://unix.stackexchange.com/

Comment: That fixed it. Post it as an answer and I will accept it.

Comment: Keith got there at the same time as I did -- and also, I actually agree that it's off-topic here.

Comment: Keith's hint about UTF-8 led to an alternate solution, changing my Putty terminal from its default character set to UTF-8. I prefer the LC_ALL=C solution since I dislike "smart" quotes.

Comment: @TeasingDart: If you set PuTTY to UTF-8 (that's not the default?), it will still display ASCII correctly.

Comment: The default is "ISO-8859-1:1998 (Latin-1, West Europe)". The best solution is to do both, but I like LC_ALL=C because I prefer the fancy quotes to never be printed at all.

Comment: Other things will be breaking left and right if your terminal has the wrong character encoding set up.  You should set it to UTF-8 regardless of this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a locale problem.

`rm` is trying to print the left and right single quotation mark characters, probably in UTF-8. Either modify your locale settings so it uses only ASCII (`export LANG=C` will do that), or, better, configure your terminal emulator so it handles UTF-8 properly.

The `locale` command will show you your current locale settings, which are controlled by setting environment variables.  Here's mine, just as an example:

```
$ locale
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE=C
LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=
```